# How to get file length in Go dynamically?

Tags: file, go

I have the following code snippet:

```
func main() {
    // Some text we want to compress.
    original := "bird and frog"
    
    // Open a file for writing.
    f, _ := os.Create("C:\\programs\\file.gz")
    
    // Create gzip writer.
    w := gzip.NewWriter(f)
    
    // Write bytes in compressed form to the file.
    while ( looping over database cursor) {
       w.Write([]byte(/* the row from the database as obtained from cursor */))
    }
    
    // Close the file.
    w.Close()
    
    fmt.Println("DONE")
}
```

However, I wish to know a small modification. When the size of file reaches a certain threshold I want to close it and open a new file. And that too in compressed format.

For example:

Assume a database has 10 rows each row is 50 bytes.

Assume compression factor is 2, ie 1 row of 50 bytes is compressed to 25 bytes.

Assume a file size limit is 50 bytes.

Which means after every 2 records I should close the file and open a new file.

How to keep track of the file size while its still open and still writing compressed documents to it ?

Comment: "f, _ := os.Create("C:\\programs\\file.gz")" Get out of the habit of ignoring errors right away.  You may be used to languages which throw exceptions when errors occur; Go's equivalent , generally, is `error` return values.  So never, ever ignore them because you're just shooting yourself in the foot for later debugging.  Note that if the Open failed in your case , `f` would be nil and your program would throw a nil pointer panic some place below.

Comment: You're ignoring the error of `Write()` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`os.File.Seek`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Seek) method to get your current position in the file, which as you're writing the file will be the current file size in bytes.

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Some text we want to compress.
    lines := []string{
        "this is a test",
        "the quick brown fox",
        "jumped over the lazy dog",
        "the end",
    }

    // Open a file for writing.
    f, err := os.Create("file.gz")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Create gzip writer.
    w := gzip.NewWriter(f)

    // Write bytes in compressed form to the file.
    for _, line := range lines {
        w.Write([]byte(line))

        w.Flush()
        pos, err := f.Seek(0, os.SEEK_CUR)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("pos: %d\n", pos)
    }

    // Close the file.
    w.Close()

    // The call to w.Close() will write out any remaining data
    // and the final checksum.
    pos, err := f.Seek(0, os.SEEK_CUR)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("pos: %d\n", pos)

    fmt.Println("DONE")
}
```

Which outputs:

```
pos: 30
pos: 55
pos: 83
pos: 94
pos: 107
DONE
```

And we can confirm with `wc`:

```
$ wc -c file.gz
107 file.gz
```

Comment: os.SEEK_CUR is deprecated, please suggest ! Thanks

Comment: Is it? I didn't see it marked as such [in the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/os#pkg-constants), not do I see any sort of deprecation warning with go version 1.19.

Comment: do not know why my editor marked it as deprecated, however I am struggling to obtain the same result on compression.

Comment: I've updated the example to use the `gzip` module.

Answer (score 2):

[`gzip.NewWriter`](https://pkg.go.dev/compress/gzip@go1.19.1#NewWriter) takes a [`io.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer). It is easy to implement custom `io.Writer` that does what you want.

E.g. [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/7SmIQNQswi1)

```
type MultiFileWriter struct {
    maxLimit      int
    currentSize   int
    currentWriter io.Writer
}

func (m *MultiFileWriter) Write(data []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if len(data)+m.currentSize > m.maxLimit {
        m.currentWriter = createNextFile()
    }
    m.currentSize += len(data)
    return m.currentWriter.Write(data)
}
```

Note: You will need to handle few edge cases like what if `len(data)` is greater than the `maxLimit`. And may be you don't want to split a record across files.